# Linux bash; manipulate PATH type var

Tags: bash, shell, variable-substitution

Linux debian bash.
I have a PATH type variable 'X' that I want to manipulate.
'X' can be any number of elements delimited by ":"
For example, using fruits:

```
set X=apple:pear:orange:cherry
```

How might I extract the first element minus its delimiter, saving it into a new variable 'Y', and then remove it and its delimiter from 'X'. As in..

`apple:pear:orange:cherry`

becomes

`Y=apple`
`X=pear:orange:cherry`

I have looked at bash substitution cheat sheets, but it's mind boggling. Sed is also a way, but I can never seem to get rid of the delimiters.

I did get this far

```
IFS=: arr=($X)
Y=${arr[0]}
cnt=${#arr[@]}
IFS=
```

Which isn't very far,  but at least I get Y but it doesn't do anything with X. To be honest, I dont understand them anyway , just used a cheat sheet. So explanations with solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does [Splitting string by the first occurrence of a delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53310/3645) work for you?

Comment: `set X=apple:pear:orange:cherry` Do you understand what `set` does?

Comment: Using an actual bash array would be easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
X=apple:pear:orange:cherry
IFS=: read -r Y X <<<"$X"    # note - will fail with newlines
declare -p Y X
# declare -- Y="apple"
# declare -- X="pear:orange:cherry"
```

`read` will assign the first element to `Y` and then the rest to `X`. For more information, see documentation of `read` and of your shell, in particular [`man 1p read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/read.1p.html) and [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) and [POSIX read](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/read.html).

But using arrays with splitting would be fine too. Fun fact - it can be one line.

```
X=apple:pear:orange:cherry
IFS=:
arr=($X)
Y=${arr[0]}
X="${arr[*]:1}"
declare -p Y X
# declare -- Y="apple"
# declare -- X="pear:orange:cherry"
```

`($X)` will do [word splitting expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and assign an [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html). With `${arr[0]` the first element is extracted. The `arr[*]` joins the array elements using first character in IFS and using `${  :1}` expansion all elements except the first are extracted, see [shell parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: Thank you. This did the job,

Answer (score 1):

You can split your colon-separated string up into an array, manipulate that, and then rebuild a new string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

x=apple:pear:orange:cherry

echo "x is $x"


IFS=:
# Split x up into an array using the value of IFS as the delimiter.
read -r -a xarr <<< "$x"
# Assign the first element to y
y=${xarr[0]}
# And remove it from the array.
unset "xarr[0]"
# Rebuild x without the first element.
x="${xarr[*]}"
unset -v IFS

echo "y is $y and x is now $x"
```